# Cannot Open fi-site-init.el

Tags: emacs, lisp

Lately i've been trying to install ELI on my Linux computer!
I've followed the guide from http://www.franz.com/emacs/ to make it work! I've also searched for similar errors and found this thread http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1646855
However unlike the person in the forum I cannot load the fi-site-init.el file from the *scratch* buffer.
By opening emacs with the --debug-init flag i get the following error messege

```
  Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "fi-site-init.el")
  load("fi-site-init.el")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/simon/.emacs" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 82
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/simon/.emacs" "/home/simon/.emacs" t t)
  load("~/.emacs" t t)
  #[nil "\205\264
```

What can be worth noticing is that in the guide they have

> "/usr/local/acl82express/eli"

as the search path while i'm having

> "/usr/Documents/acl82express/eli"

as path (since Allegro CL is installed there)

All in all this is what I've writed in the .emacs file

```
 (push "/usr/Documents/acl82express/eli" load-path)
  (load "fi-site-init.el")
  (setq fi:common-lisp-image-name "/usr/Documents/acl82express/alisp")
  (setq fi:common-lisp-image-file "/usr/Documents/acl82express/alisp.dxl")
  (setq fi:common-lisp-directory "/usr/Documents/acl82express")
```

I am thankful for any help!

Simon Nyström

Comment: I wasn't really sure how i was going to change. I changed load-path to require but that didn't work (gave me an another error message) and I  also tried to write the entire path on line 2. That didn't make any difference and I got the same error message as before.

Comment: I knew it would be some simple fault! Changed the path to ~/Documents/  and it helped! Thank you! Rewrite what you said as an answer to my question and you will get some credits for it, and once again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documents is typically the name of the directory in the user home directory. It is customary to find it under `/home/{user}/Documents` where {user} is the currently logged in user. `who am i | awk '{ print $1 }'` - this is the way to find out, unless you forget :)

This directory is often times aliased with ~ (tilde) or `$HOME` environmental variable, so that when doing path expansion happens these "$HOME/Documents", "~/Documents" and "/home/{user}/Documents" will all point to the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the leading "/"-symbol. I'm quite sure it'd have to be "/usr/Documents/acl82express/eli" for you.

Comment: I can't belive I forgot to mention that I've tried that (and it didn't help). Thanks anyway

Comment: Can you add the essential snip from your .emacs-file to your question? There's most likely just some mistake in the syntax.

Comment: Done! Thanks for taking the time to look over my problem!

Comment: The syntax seems OK... Make sure that the file /usr/Documents/acl82express/eli/fi-site-init.el really is there. Can't really think of anything else making it not work.

Comment: Confirmed! Since I am kind of new to Linux i write the entire address to the directory just to make sure nothing as simple as that is wrong     "/home/simon/Documents/acl82express/eli"

Comment: have you tried printing/viewing your load path after you set it? Ensure that it's actually being set.

Comment: Well I guess not! How can i do that in a simple way?

Comment: @korsnas Type `load-path` in your scratch buffer, then press C-j (control and j)

Comment: Hmm. Didn't really understand if you meant (load-path) as a commando or (load "my path"). If i wrote load-path alone in the scratch buffer the following code "popped" out `code  ("/usr/share/emacs23/s/emacs-goodies-el" "/usr/share/emacs23/site-lisp/dictionaries-common" "/etc/emacs23" "/etc/emacs" "/usr/local/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp" "/usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp" "/usr/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp" "/usr/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp/dictionaries-common" "/usr/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp/emacs-goodies-el" "/usr/share/emacs/23.3/site-lisp/slime" ...)`

Comment: I have Slime installed (but not working). Do you think that can sabotage some things?